# process memory size solaris

Tags: linux, unix, solaris, system-administration, solaris-10

Running perl script in solaris 10 machine.  Know the RAM Size is 25 GB.  Have two queries.

1. Normally How much RAM memory  a solaris process is allocated. Is it a default value assigned to any script or process. where it can be set?   How do i determine how much max  static array size can i have and how much dynamic memory can i allocate? what command i need to issue to find it out what memory allocated to a process in solaris? Is it configurable?
2. When the script gives me outofmemory error. Does it mean it used the entire RAM and virtual memory?  Is there any way to know how memory was used when the script threw out ofmemory error?what command i need to issue to find it out in solaris?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) As much as it requests, up to the limit set by [ulimit](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/ulimit-1.html#scrolltoc).   Commands such as [pmap](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/pmap-1.html#scrolltoc) and [ps](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/ps-1.html#scrolltoc) can show how much a process has allocated at the current time.

2) It can mean that it used all virtual memory, or that it hit the process limit, or that it's a 32-bit process and hit the 4gb address space limit.  [*Solaris Application Memory Management*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris10/solaris-memory-135224.html) provides some more details.